# how to put angle brackets in gnuplot labels?

Tags: gnuplot

I've have simply tried < >, but I almost sure there exist something more beautiful. More "open" let's say. Like the ones here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Answer (score 1):

Then, use UTF-8 encoding and an appropriate font which contains the requested glyphs and go ahead:

```
set terminal wxt font "Dejavu Sans"
set encoding utf8
set label "⟨uv⟩" at graph 0.05,0.5 left font ",30"
plot x
```

Which gives (using gnuplot 5.0)

[image]

Or, for more sophisticated typesetting, use one of the LaTeX-based terminals.

Comment: Congrats on the gold gnuplot badge!

Comment: @mgilson Thanks! Quite some work on such a low-traffic tag :)

Comment: I know.  I remember the struggles to get upvotes on the gnuplot tag quite well :-).